# how to retrieve firebase data on first click using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, async-await

when I click login button following code executes,

```
function login(){
    var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("Password").value;
    var Real_email="";
    var Real_password="";
        firebase.database().ref('/login').on('value',function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot){
            Real_email=childsnapshot.val().email;
            Real_password=childsnapshot.val().password;
            alert("test");
            })
        });
    if(email==Real_email && password==Real_password){
        alert("correct username and password");
        }else{
        alert("Wrong username or password");    
        }
    }
```

on the first button click it gives the unexpected output.
The output order is,

1. Wrong username or password.
2. test.(after some time...)

but when I click the login button again (2nd click) it provides the expected output.
The output order is,

1. test.
2. correct username and password.

I tried below code also,

```
async function login(){
    var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var password=document.getElementById("Password").value;
    var Real_email="";
    var Real_password="";
        await firebase.database().ref('/login').on('value',function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function (childsnapshot){
            Real_email=childsnapshot.val().email;
            Real_password=childsnapshot.val().password;
            alert("test");
            })
        });
    if(email==Real_email && password==Real_password){
        alert("correct username and password");
        }else{
        alert("Wrong username or password");    
        }
    }
```

but it returns same result.

Therefore how to retrieve firebase real time database data on first click using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote sets a callback method when there is result from the firebase call. It is executed in parallel with the rest of the code and sometimes if is faster sometimes not, depending on internet connectivity, etc.

Usually the first call creates the connection to the remote server and this is usually slower. Next calls (second click and so on) there is existing connection that is reused and therefore is faster and gets executed faster.

Because of the asynchronous code, in order to achieve the result you are looking for, you may want to put the if(email==Real_email && password==Real_password)  inside the callback in the place of the alert(). An option 2 is if you make the call blocking, but this is extremely bad idea and bad practice, because you "main JS thread" will hang, even some older browsers may hang also.